# Query regarding setting ESP32 eFuses for restricting USB firmware access

Tags: esp32

I am currently working on a project where I need to restrict the ability to read and write firmware through the USB interface on the ESP32. To achieve this, I have attempted to set the following eFuses for experimentation purposes: UART_DOWNLOAD_DIS (BLOCK0), DISABLE_DL_ENCRYPT (BLOCK0), and DISABLE_DL_DECRYPT (BLOCK0). However, despite setting these eFuses, I am still able to burn code into the ESP32.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in identifying what might be causing this issue. Am I setting the correct eFuses for my requirement? If not, could you please advise me on the correct eFuses to set in order to prevent USB firmware access?

Thank you for your time and expertise.

```
=== Run "summary" command ===
EFUSE_NAME (Block) Description  = [Meaningful Value] [Readable/Writeable] (Hex Value)
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Calibration fuses:
BLK3_PART_RESERVE (BLOCK0):                        BLOCK3 partially served for ADC calibration data   = False R/W (0b0)
ADC_VREF (BLOCK0):                                 Voltage reference calibration                      = 1079 R/W (0b10011)

Config fuses:
XPD_SDIO_FORCE (BLOCK0):                           Ignore MTDI pin (GPIO12) for VDD_SDIO on reset     = False R/W (0b0)
XPD_SDIO_REG (BLOCK0):                             If XPD_SDIO_FORCE, enable VDD_SDIO reg on reset    = False R/W (0b0)
XPD_SDIO_TIEH (BLOCK0):                            If XPD_SDIO_FORCE & XPD_SDIO_REG                   = 1.8V R/W (0b0)
CLK8M_FREQ (BLOCK0):                               8MHz clock freq override                           = 54 R/W (0x36)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CLK (BLOCK0):                       Override SD_CLK pad (GPIO6/SPICLK)                 = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_Q (BLOCK0):                         Override SD_DATA_0 pad (GPIO7/SPIQ)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_D (BLOCK0):                         Override SD_DATA_1 pad (GPIO8/SPID)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_HD (BLOCK0):                        Override SD_DATA_2 pad (GPIO9/SPIHD)               = 0 R/W (0b00000)
SPI_PAD_CONFIG_CS0 (BLOCK0):                       Override SD_CMD pad (GPIO11/SPICS0)                = 0 R/W (0b00000)
DISABLE_SDIO_HOST (BLOCK0):                        Disable SDIO host                                  = False R/W (0b0)

Efuse fuses:
WR_DIS (BLOCK0):                                   Efuse write disable mask                           = 0 R/W (0x0000)
RD_DIS (BLOCK0):                                   Efuse read disable mask                            = 0 R/W (0x0)
CODING_SCHEME (BLOCK0):                            Efuse variable block length scheme
   = NONE (BLK1-3 len=256 bits) R/W (0b00)
KEY_STATUS (BLOCK0):                               Usage of efuse block 3 (reserved)                  = False R/W (0b0)

Identity fuses:
MAC (BLOCK0):                                      Factory MAC Address
   = 7c:9e:bd:45:7d:c0 (CRC 0x0d OK) R/W
MAC_CRC (BLOCK0):                                  CRC8 for factory MAC address                       = 13 R/W (0x0d)
CHIP_VER_REV1 (BLOCK0):                            Silicon Revision 1                                 = True R/W (0b1)
CHIP_VER_REV2 (BLOCK0):                            Silicon Revision 2                                 = False R/W (0b0)
WAFER_VERSION_MINOR (BLOCK0):                      WAFER VERSION MINOR                                = 0 R/W (0b00)
CHIP_PACKAGE (BLOCK0):                             Chip package identifier                            = 0 R/W (0b000)
CHIP_PACKAGE_4BIT (BLOCK0):                        Chip package identifier #4bit                      = 0 R/W (0b0)
MAC_VERSION (BLOCK3):                              Version of the MAC field                           = 0 R/W (0x00)
WAFER_VERSION_MAJOR (BLOCK0):                      calc WAFER VERSION MAJOR from CHIP_VER_REV1 and CH = 1 R/W (0b001)
                                                   IP_VER_REV2 and apb_ctl_date (read only)
PKG_VERSION (BLOCK0):                              calc Chip package = CHIP_PACKAGE_4BIT << 3 + CHIP_ = 0 R/W (0x0)
                                                   PACKAGE (read only)

Security fuses:
FLASH_CRYPT_CNT (BLOCK0):                          Flash encryption mode counter                      = 0 R/W (0b0000000)
UART_DOWNLOAD_DIS (BLOCK0):                        Disable UART download mode (ESP32 rev3 only)       = True R/W (0b1)
FLASH_CRYPT_CONFIG (BLOCK0):                       Flash encryption config (key tweak bits)           = 0 R/W (0x0)
CONSOLE_DEBUG_DISABLE (BLOCK0):                    Disable ROM BASIC interpreter fallback             = True R/W (0b1)
ABS_DONE_0 (BLOCK0):                               Secure boot V1 is enabled for bootloader image     = False R/W (0b0)
ABS_DONE_1 (BLOCK0):                               Secure boot V2 is enabled for bootloader image     = False R/W (0b0)
JTAG_DISABLE (BLOCK0):                             Disable JTAG                                       = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_ENCRYPT (BLOCK0):                       Disable flash encryption in UART bootloader        = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_DECRYPT (BLOCK0):                       Disable flash decryption in UART bootloader        = False R/W (0b0)
DISABLE_DL_CACHE (BLOCK0):                         Disable flash cache in UART bootloader             = False R/W (0b0)
BLOCK1 (BLOCK1):                                   Flash encryption key
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK2 (BLOCK2):                                   Secure boot key
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W
BLOCK3 (BLOCK3):                                   Variable Block 3
   = 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 R/W

Flash voltage (VDD_SDIO) determined by GPIO12 on reset
```

Comment: research `ESP32 fuse calculator`